# OpenGL Instancing VBO - Attribute per Vertex, per Instance

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vbo

As I understand it, glDrawArraysInstanced() will draw a VBO **n** times. glVertexAttribDivisor() using 1, so that each instance has a unique attribute in the shader. So far I can pass a different color for each instance, with **vec4*instances**, and each vertex in that instance will share that attribute, hence each instance of a triangle has a different color.

However, what I'm looking for is a type of divisor that will advance the attribute per vertex for each instance, and the best example would be a different color for each vertex in a triangle, for each instance. I would fill a VBO with **3*vec4*instances**.

Eg. I want to draw 2 triangles using instancing:

```
color_vbo [] = {
    vec4, vec4, vec4, // first triangle's vertex colors
    vec4, vec4, vec4 // second triangle's vertex colors
}; // Imagine this is data in a VBO

glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3(vertexes), 2(instances));
```

If I set the attribute divisor to **0**, it will use the first 3 colors of the color_vbo everywhere, rather than advancing. 
Effectively each vertex should get the attribute from the VBO as if it were:

```
color_attribute = color_vbo[(vertex_count * current_instance) + current_vertex];
```

Comment: I am in the same situation. I need one vec2 for each vertex. And each instance has 4 vertexes, using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. So I have a mat4x2 to put the instanced data to one instance. And then using mat4x2[gl_VertexID] to access only one vec2 for each vertex. I think the theory should be correct. Unfortunately, the render result is not desired, very random.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you're asking for is possible using vertex attribute divisors.

It is possible to do this sort of thing using a technique described in [OpenGL Insights](http://openglinsights.com/bendingthepipeline.html) as "Programmable Vertex Pulling", where you read vertex data from a texture buffer using whatever calculation you like (using `gl_VertexID` and `gl_InstanceID`).

Another possibility would be to use three vertex attributes (each with a divisor of 1) to store the colours of each triangle point and use `gl_VertexID` to choose which of the attributes to use for any given vertex. Obviously this solution doesn't scale to having much more than three vertices per instance.

Comment: Is it possible then to not have 3 separate attributes just for colors, but possibly use one attribute as an array? If you ask me, I'm actually surprised this is uncommon and wasn't thought through with OpenGL. disappoint...

Comment: No, you can't have arrays of vertex attributes. To be fair, I don't think it's possible to have an API which enables every possible usage scenario (although I agree yours is a reasonable thing to want to do) and can still be implemented efficiently. If you want to do something differently to the ways that OpenGL provides, you'll have to look to more inventive techniques such as "Programmable Vertex Pulling" which is in the "Bending the Pipeline" (the clue's in the title) section of the OpenGL Insights book.

Comment: @Luka: you actually _could_ abouse the GL to use a limited set of attributes like an array - by declaring a matrix attribute (which will take up to 4 attribute vector "slots"), and can use the [] operator on the matrix to select a specific vec4. However, that would be very ineffcient, and I would strongly suggest following GuyRT's advice.